# Can mobile db's be modified after installation and still work?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to know if it is possible to add a table to my remote database after the app has been running on my device for a couple of weeks, and still work?

For instance, if I'm using a Android device and have a simple game with 3 levels using SQLite db. Now I want to add a 4th level to the game, without losing progress on the other 3 levels or having to re install the app to accommodate for db changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words `YES` it's possible. You can change your database design with out losing any data. You can achieve by overriding the 'onUpgrade' method in your database class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

You need to change the database version number when you update your app. If the database version number is greater than the previous one then `onUpgrade` method get called.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int newVersionNumber, int oldVersionNumber) {  
      // Do your Changes here. You can Alter table, Drop column etc
}
```

Remote Database - Its not linked with app. So you can change what ever you want. It won't affect your app. But you need to handle it efficiently.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ohke this helps a lot, thank you. Does the same apply for local db's? Ie, can I make changes to the db on the mobile device without losing data or having to re install it?

Comment: Yes the top part i explained is for local db.

Comment: No problems. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is possible, you can upgrade it.

You must set old and new database version.

> public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int newVersionNumber, int
>   oldVersionNumber)